# Un inanimé « retrouve de sa superbe » : sens en contexte etc. ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, registre, évolution

On titre dans un article :

> Le box-office retrouve de sa superbe.

[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/superbe#Nom_commun) parle de « grandeur » et donne des exemples récents tandis que le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/superbe/1) indique *littéraire* et donne « orgueil mêlé de dédain exprimant un sentiment de supériorité ».

> [...] La superbe, condamné par Vaugelas (1647), est tombé en désuétude
> jusqu'au XIX e siècle. Le mot a été repris dans un style littéraire,
> au sens « d'assurance orgueilleuse qui se manifeste par l'air, le
> maintien » (1849, Michelet).
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. Rey, Le
> Robert, 2011 ]

---

1. Quel est le sens exact (synonyme) dans le titre ; est-ce un emploi
   typique ?
2. Le sens de *grandeur* est-il une extension de sens moderne du sens
   d'*assurance orgueilleuse* ; l'emploi est-il littéraire ?
3. Pourquoi Vaugelas a-t-il (aussi) condamné cet emploi ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Il a retrouvé son lustre, le prestige qu'il avait perdu entretemps. C'est un emploi soutenu et plus courant associé avec perdre. L'usage est d'ailleurs réduit à quelques combinaisons assez figées : *perdre (un peu/beaucoup) de sa superbe*, *ne rien perdre de sa superbe* ou ici, *retrouver de sa superbe*.
2. Oui, grandeur est ici à prendre au sens figuré, l'opposé de petitesse (mesquin). Il me semble que l'emploi moderne avec *retrouver* ne contient pas l'aspect méprisant décrit dans la définition du TLFi (dédain, sentiment de supériorité). Quand la superbe est perdue, il est au contraire bien présent.
3. Vaugelas considérait que *superbe* n'était qu'un adjectif et refusait donc son utilisation comme substantif.

[image]

*[Remarques sur la langue françoise : utiles à ceux qui veulent bien parler et bien escrire](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k84316s/f83.item)*, 1647